# Remove TCP option using scapy

Tags: python, scapy, netfilter

I'm using scapy and NetFilterQueue to manipulate IP packets between client and server.
[image]

I would like to remove the last option in the TCP header option field list. Removing an option in the TCP header changes the size of the packet and whenever I change the size packet leads to packet drop at both client and server-side.

I tried to recalculate the length of both IP & TCP but still doesn't work. Here is my complete code and I'm using scapy version 2.4.5.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2.7
from scapy.all import *
from netfilterqueue import NetfilterQueue
import os

iptablesr = "iptables -A FORWARD -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1"

os.system(iptablesr)
os.system("sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1")

def check_mptcp_option(option_list):
    for option in option_list:
        if option[0] == 30:
            return True
    return False

def modify(packet):
    ip_pkt = IP(packet.get_payload())
    try:
        ip_tcp = ip_pkt.getlayer(TCP)
        if check_mptcp_option(ip_tcp.options):
            payload_before = len(ip_pkt[TCP])
            ip_pkt[TCP].options = ip_pkt[TCP].options[:-1] # remove last option
            payload_after = len(ip_pkt[TCP])
            payload_dif = payload_after - payload_before
            ip_pkt[IP].len = ip_pkt[IP].len + payload_dif
            del ip_pkt[IP].chksum
            del ip_pkt[TCP].chksum
            packet.set_payload(str(ip_pkt))
        packet.accept()
            
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        packet.accept() #just skip the packet unmodified.
        
def main():
    nfqueue = NetfilterQueue()
    nfqueue.bind(1, modify)
    try:
        print "[*] waiting for data"
        nfqueue.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        nfqueue.unbind()
        print "Flushing iptables."
        os.system('iptables -F')
        os.system('iptables -X')
       
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Note**: If I do anything without changing the size of the packet it works (for example modifying the TCP option instead of removing it).

Comment: You may need to set the fields to none, or do something else to force scapy to recompute those fields.  You shouldn't have to compute them yourself, though.

Comment: I tried none and it doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure you're not swallowing an important exception?

Comment: @alex.forencich :) Yepp.. in real code I have print statement everywhere so I removed them when posting them in StackOverflow.

Comment: @alex.forencich looks like changing packet length affect the seq number and that's the reason for packet drop.

Comment: @alex.forencich looks like changing packet length affect the seq number and that's the reason for packet drop.

Comment: Changing the length of the header should not affect the sequence number

Comment: Ah you are right, but somewhere should I need to specify header length ?

Comment: TCP data offset

Comment: Sounds right to me. Try setting all of those to None and see if scapy will recompute them. They really need to add a method to reset all of these computed fields so they will be recomputed.